# Make conditional react component rerender after boolean changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boo

I have a react component that conditionally renders JSX according to the user's login state.

```
<div>
    { boolIsLoggedIn ?
    <SomeLoggedInComponent /> : <SomeNotLoggedInComponent /> }
</div>
```

I think I need to use `React.useState()` and/or `React.useEffect()` but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it.

I've tried this:

```
const [boolIsLoggedIn, setBoolIsLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedIn())

useEffect(() => {
  const checkLogIn = () => {
    setBoolIsLoggedIn(isLoggedIn())
  }

  checkLogIn()
})
```

Where isLoggedIn() checks whether the user is logged in or not and returns a boolean.

Currently, I can log out and log in and the `isLoggedIn()` function works, but the component I want to conditionally re-render doesn't do so until I refresh the page.

---

So I added `[isLoggedin()]` as the second parameter to `useEffect()` and now it ***almost*** works. When I log in, the `boolIsLoggedIn` value changes to true and the component re-renders. However, when I log back out `boolIsLoggedIn` doesn't change until I refresh the page.
Here is my code for the isLoggedIn() function, which is coded in a seperate file and imported:

```
let boolIsLoggedIn = false

export const setUser = user => {
  //handle login
  boolIsLoggedIn = true

export const logout => {
  //handle logout
  boolIsLoggedIn = false
}

export const isLoggedIn = () =>
    return boolIsLoggedIn
}
```

Comment: your useEffect is triggered after every state update so you need to update your state to run it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn()
    };
  }

  render() {
    let { isLoggedIn } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
       
        {(function() {
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return <div>Login</div>;
          } else {
            return <div>with out Login</div>;
          }
        })()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing the open [ on defining the state.
2. I would set the defailt value on false so you won't execute the function twice.
3. The use effect usually needs a dependencies array as the second parameter but as you only want to run it once (after the component is mounted) just place an empty array as the second parameter.
4. Another thing is that if the `isLoggedIn` function is asyncronous you have to wait for it by using await and setting the parent function as async. This would definetly be the problem you have if the function is asyncronous.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I added `isLoggedIn()` to the `useEffect()` dependencies and it almost works. I've edited the question to also include the `isLoggedIn()` function.

Comment: Also add the logout function that you use in the dependency list.

Comment: It looks like the `boolIsLoggedIn` variable changes to true when I log in, but when I log out it stays equal to true. This is what is causing the component not to rerender, the variable isnt changing. Not sure why it's not changing back to false thought, as my logout function clearly sets `boolIsLoggedIn = false`

Comment: Export it and use it as a dependency in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

```
const boolIsLoggedIn, setBoolIsLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedIn())

useEffect(() => {
  const checkLogIn = () => {
    setBoolIsLoggedIn(isLoggedIn())
  }

  checkLogIn()
})
```

To this:

```
const [boolIsLoggedIn, setBoolIsLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedIn());

  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      setBoolIsLoggedIn(isLoggedIn());
    })();
  }, [isLoggedIn()]);
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to share react state, and not just values in order to trigger a react re-render. In your example, you would need a call to `setBoolIsLoggedIn()` whenever value of `isLoggedIn()` changes in order to change the state and trigger a re-render of the component.

Another way share state between components is through React Context. You would first need to create a Context Provider like this:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState({ loggedIn: false });

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={[ user, setUser ]}>
            { children }
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

In this case, the `UserProvider` is the one maintaining the shared state with`user={ loggedIn }`. You would then need to wrap your React App component with this provider in order for components to be able to share state.

To set the shared `user` state you can use the hook `useContext(UserContext)` and change state through `setUser` provided by the hook. In the example below, we have a login button component that sets shared `user` state:

```
function LoginButton() {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

  /** flip login state when button is clicked */
  function logIn() {
    setUser(state => ({ ...state, loggedIn: !state.loggedIn }) );
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={logIn}>{ user.loggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In"}</button>
  );
}
```

And finally, to be able to use the shared `user` state and trigger a re-render whenever the user state changes, you would again use the hook `useContext(UserContext)` in a different component to be able to get the state like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [user,] = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Conditional React component</h1>
      <h2>Click on the button to login/logout</h2>
      <LoginButton></LoginButton>

      <div>
        { user.loggedIn ? <LoggedInComponent/> : <LoggedOutComponent/>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've provided an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-grass-915xl) to show how this all works together.